# 'Remember me' option is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, custom-authentication

I am using asp.net mvc4. In my login page I've kept the 'Remember me' option. But looks like it's not working.

I saved my authcookie like this:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                            userName, // user name
                            DateTime.Now,             //creation
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), //Expiration
                            persistanceFlag, //Persistent
                            usrData); //Saving user data

var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I am using form authentication. I've checked the authentication in my CustomAuthorizeAttribute class which implements 'AuthorizeAttribute' interface.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // auth failed, redirect to login page

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Security/UserAccount/SignIn");
        }
    }
}
```

But It's like my process is not handling 'Remember me' option. When I login choosing the 'Remember me' option and then close and reopen the browser, again it ask for login.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value if persistanceFlag, this should be true.

Is this changing?

Comment: Yes when 'Remember me' option is selected then the value is true. I've checked that.